# Reading large gpkg file in R

Tags: shapefile, r

I would like to read one variable (column) from a very large gpkg file (20GB) into R. It has only one layer. Is it any way to get one column (I assume that it is a character type but it could be a numeric one, I am not sure how this data is stored). 
I tried this way:

```
df_pi <- st_read("All_DB2_Shapes.gpkg", query = "SELECT POLY_ID")
```

But I received this message:

> Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  : 
>    SQL execution failed, cannot open layer.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
>    GDAL Error 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT POLY_ID):
>    no such column: POLY_ID

If I just try to open it with st_read command then it cannot manage it because of the lack of memory.

Comment: Why are you using `system.file` with a package? That looks for files installed with a package. If I do: `system.file("foo.gpkg",package="sf")` it returns `""` which will lead to your error. Just give the path to the geopackage.

Comment: Thanks, however, it still does not work. I do not know how to open it without all the other attributes and run this query, so it would only read that particular variable that I need. I cannot open the whole thing because it is too big to handle for R.

Comment: I found out that the variable I need (POLY_ID) is a numeric one.

Comment: Edit your question and show what you tried and give the new error message.

Comment: I set up wd where the package is stored.

Answer (score 5):

I can now duplicate your error with a test package I've made:

```
> d = st_read("/tmp/test.gpkg",query="select resolution")
Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  : 
  Query execution failed, cannot open layer.
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Error 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(select resolution):
  no such column: resolution
```

That error is because the query doesn't define which table it is trying to select `resolution` from. Let's add that:

```
> d = st_read("/tmp/test.gpkg",query="select resolution from test")
Reading layer `test' from data source `/tmp/test.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
Warning message:
no simple feature geometries present: returning a data.frame or tbl_df
```

Now because I'm only selecting one column there's no geometry. `d` is a simple data frame with no spatial data.

```
> class(d)
[1] "data.frame"
> head(d)
  resolution
1         10
2         10
3         10
```

If that's what you want - just the column data and not the locations - then that's answered. If you also want the location info, add it to the query:

```
> d = st_read("/tmp/test.gpkg",query="select resolution,geom from test")
Reading layer `test' from data source `/tmp/test.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
Simple feature collection with 8621 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -11.11163 ymin: 49.76681 xmax: 2.513016 ymax: 61.58096
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Now I have a spatial object with polygons.

I can refine this query with a `where` clause if I want to select fewer elements:

```
> d = st_read("/tmp/test.gpkg",query="select resolution,geom from test where resolution > 10")
Reading layer `test' from data source `/tmp/test.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
Simple feature collection with 1583 features and 1 field
```

So the short answer is "add the layer name so the query knows which layer to select from".

Comment: It worked, thanks. However, it is still using too much memory, so I cannot get the data into R.

Comment: how many rows are you expecting? You can get the total number of rows of GPKG layer called `grid` from file `bto.gpkg` with `st_read("bto.gpkg",query="select count(*) from grid")` BUT again, edit your question and show the error message.

Comment: The error message is that there is not enough memory. Although I know the number of rows: 29351312.

Comment: Are you also trying to read the geometry? What are you running? Can you read in a small number of rows by doing something like `query="select X from Y LIMIT 100"` - which should only read 100 rows? Please edit your question and show your command and paste your error message in.

Comment: I run this code `db2.df1 <- read_sf("All_DB2_Shapes.gpkg", query = "SELECT POLY_ID, geom from DB2_Shapes LIMIT 10000000" )` and it could have been executed. Is there any way to define which rows I want to be read, so I could read the data in three steps?

Comment: I solved this last bit. The code looks like this `db2.df2 <- read_sf("All_DB2_Shapes.gpkg", query = "SELECT POLY_ID, geom from DB2_Shapes LIMIT 10000000 OFFSET 10000000")` so it would ignore the first 10000000 records.